# Subset of Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Then is $u$ Lipchitz continuous?

I am either unable to prove or disprove it.

Can someone kindly help me with an argument?

Thanks.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** All partial derivatives are continuous functions on a compact set, and hence bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much.